# Unable to import the .pfx file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While running the application getting below error in Visual Studio.

Build started...

1>------ Build started: Project: MFA, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3326,5): error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: newtest.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_8ABCA7C8F0781B15

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3326,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "newtest.pfx" was canceled.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: how do you create the key file? how do you import the key file? what is your current project type?

Comment: is any update? we are waiting for your update.